# Issue with RaspBMC and displaying movies/tvshows on the website/remote apps

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I recently installed RaspBMC and I am having a few issues. XBMC won't display movies/tv shows on phone apps or its own little website, on the website it just sits there loading forever. I don't know if this is due to a large amount of media however I did let XBMC index it all over a day and it finished without any issues.

This is the first time I have used XBMC so I may have set something up incorrectly however I have done a lot of googling and made sure all my settings are correct.

I have enabled control of XBMC via HTTP.

I have allowed programs on this system and on other systems to control XBMC.

I have made sure its static IP is correct and it can download updates etc. fine.

I have tested different iPhone/Windows Phone apps and all have the same issues.

I have over 700 movies and 50 TV Shows. They are split into 2 different folders, TV shows and Movies then each show/movie has there own subfolder.

I am at a loss as to why I can do these things and would appreciate any help.

Also I just noticed when trying to view things on the web interface I get the following JavaScript errors.

When viewing TV Shows:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tvshows' of undefined [`http://192.168.0.17/js/MediaLibrary.js?0.7405579637270421:974`]

When viewing movies:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'movies' of undefined [`http://192.168.0.17/js/MediaLibrary.js?0.7405579637270421:918`]

However the remote on the webpage loads fine.

Comment: Those JavaScript errors look pretty relevant.

Comment: I gathered that... however I am not sure how to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I realized you have probably solved this problem by now but this may be solution for somebody else:

I believe the problem may be that you have not scanned for new content. Find where your files are from the file manager, right click and update your library ( this may take a while ), also you can set the content type with a right click and use different hosts to search for movie/tv show to obtain new cover art and descriptions.